# everyplay crashes the android game on close

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I am using Everyplay with Unity. The game is live and is called Madfinger. I have an issue on android as in when the user cancels the video ad while it is still buffering, it causes my game to crash and exits with error as "Unfortunately MadFinger has stopped working". It happens only when  buffering or loading the video ad, but it happens every single time. Can you please help me out with it? If user doesn't press back button, everything works perfectly. You can download the game from Google play and check for yourself. As the pace of game is quite high, the ad is placed on every 7th game over. The game is free btw. Thank you.